# Firefox back button behaves strangly following link to id in same page

Tags: html, dom, browser

I'm getting some weird behaviour with the Firefox back button after linking to id's in the same page. If I have some basic html like this:

```
<a href="#some_id">link to header</a>

... chunk of content ...

<h2 id="some_id">header</h2>
```

The first click on the link takes me to the header and the first click on the browser back button takes me back to the link. All good. But if I click the link again and then click the back button a second time the browser gets confused. The screen doesn't go back to the link. Worse if I scroll back then whenever the mouse hovers over the link (or even the address bar) the screen shoots back to the header without anything being clicked.

Here's the fun part. If I do click anywhere on the page after that second visit to the header then the back button works as normal. Also, if I open the dev tools overlay then the back button works as normal.

I've tried this with a totally stripped down file - just plain html with no scripts (even no css) - to remove any unseen errors.

Has anybody else run into this? Found a fix?

Comment: Hmm that's interesting, I wonder what browser it happens in and if it's happening in other browsers too?

Comment: Thanks. It's late here - I'd written in "browser" instead of specifying Firefox. I've edited the question.